# Using a for loop to set values in jTextFields taken from a database

Tags: java, swing, oop, reflection, jtextfield

I want to execute a query and add those values to text fields inside a loop. I want to have something like this,

```
String query = "select student_id,String firstName,lastName,address,phoneNumber,mobileNumber,fathersName,fathersOccupation,mothersName,nationality,qualification from student where student_id='" + jTextField5.getText().toString() + "'";
        ResultSet rs = DBOptions.executeSQLQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        for(int i=0; i < 11; i++){
            String s = rs.getString(i+1);
            String field = "jTextField"+i+".setText(s)";//can you do something like this and use the string to add values to individual textFeilds?
        }
```

I have tried looking at ArrayList and other ways but they seem confusing......

Comment: are you trying to create Jtextfield or do you want all the details from the query to be displayed within the textfield

Comment: The more common approach is to use a JTable. Read the API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables`. You can also search the web for `ResultSetTableModel` which will help you build your table.

Answer (score 0):

Store all the `jtextField` in `ArrayList`, but make sure that they are **inserted** in the **order**.

```
List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
fieldList.add(jtextField1); //gets stored at index 0
fieldList.add(jtextField2); //gets stored at index 1
...
fieldList.add(jtextField10); //gets stored at index 10
```

then in your method

```
for(int i=0; i < 11; i++){
    String s = rs.getString(i+1);
    fieldList.get(i).setText(s);
}
```

Comment: Since I have already created the text fields in NetBeans where do I create the ArrayList?

Comment: then you can already use the `arraylist` as specified in second part of my answer -  the `for-loop`

Comment: Sorry what I meant was, since NetBeans have have already generated the code for the text fields I have created earlier, do I have to delete those text fields and then create a ArrayList?

Comment: In that case, put all the textFields created by net beans into the arraylist. Keep arraylist itself as field in your class, so that you can use it later to get the jtextfield from it